# Filtering Datagridview after excel import

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using this code to import an excel sheet into the datagridview

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PartNumber"))
bs = New BindingSource
bs.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ExcelWork.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""")
MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", Con)
MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
Con.Close()
```

Now how do I filter it using a text box????

Comment: How do you want to filter it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Rowfilter** property of a **DataView**

```
Dim dv As New System.Data.DataView()
dv.Table = YourDataTable
dv.RowFilter = "Field like '%Parameter%'" 'Or "Field > 12"
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
```

**Rowfilter** would be you like the **Where** statement of an SQL query

Here are some examples
[Filter DataGridView with the text entered in TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/431281/Filter-DataGridView-with-the-text-entered-in-TextB)
[Filtering a Dataset Using Dataview](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satyapriyanayak/filtering-a-dataset-using-dataview-and-select-method-in-vb-n/)